# How to reduce multiple queries to only one query?

Tags: python, django, orm

How do I build a **single query** with djangos ORM to get the best score, lower than 1.000, for every player? I'm using django 1.7 rc2 and python 3.4.

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Player(models.Model):
    pass

class Score(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

My solution so far:

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase

from bar.models import Player, Score


class BarTest(TestCase):
    def test_do_it(self):
        p1 = Player.objects.create()
        p2 = Player.objects.create()

        Score.objects.create(player=p1, score=100)
        Score.objects.create(player=p1, score=12000)
        Score.objects.create(player=p2, score=10000)
        Score.objects.create(player=p2, score=500)
        Score.objects.create(player=p2, score=900)

        players = Player.objects.all()
        for player in players:
            score = Score.objects.filter(player=player, score__lte=1000).order_by('score').last()
            if score:
                print(player.id, score.id, score.score)
```

I don't want to iterate over every player in python and make a query for every player but instead solve this problem with only one query (without writing raw sql).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
all_scores = Score.objects.filter(score__lte=1000).order_by('player', '-score')
current_player = None
scores = []
for score in all_scores:
    if current_player != score.player:
        current_player = score.player
        scores.append(score)
```

Only one iteration over the scores. Sorting is done by the database.

**EDIT**

Finally, I found a solution:

```
Player.objects.filter(score__score__lte=1000
                     ).annotate(max_score=Max('score__score'))
```

which builds this SQL-query:

```
SELECT
    "bar_player"."id",
    MAX("bar_score"."score") AS "max_score"
FROM
    "bar_player"
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    "bar_score"
ON
    ( "bar_player"."id" = "bar_score"."player_id" )
WHERE
    "bar_score"."score" <= 1000
GROUP BY
    "bar_player"."id"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `select_related()` you can fetch all scores and their players in one go:

```
from collections import defaultdict
scores = defaultdict(list)

# Fetch all scores (with score <= 1000), including their players.
for score in Score.objects.filter(score__lte=1000).select_related('player'):
    # Group scores by their player.
    scores[score.player.id].append(score)

# Get max score for each player.
for p in scores:
    max_score = max(scores[p], key=lambda s: s.score)
    print(p, max_score.id, max_score.score)
```

Comment: With single query I meant the calculation and filtering of the max scores too (because that is what SQL is good at)!